# Python Tkinter loop cannot operate UI interface

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter. When i tried to create a loop such as `for i in range(100)`, the GUI ‘crashed’, which means I can't operate the GUI until the loop ends ( even I insert nothing to the text). After I checked some information, I tried threading. It does really work. But...

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
from threading import Thread

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('tkinter')
        self.root.geometry('400x300+400+100')
        
        self.createWidget()
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def createWidget(self):
        self.text = Text(self.root, width=40, height=15, relief=SOLID, borderwidth=1)
        self.text.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.button = Button(self.root, text="click", relief=SOLID, borderwidth=1, command=self.button_click)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0)
        pass

    def button_click(self):
        t1 = Thread(target=self.loop)
        t1.start()            
        
    def loop(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.text.insert(END, chars=str(i)+'\n')
            time.sleep(1)
            self.root.update()
            self.text.see(END)


if __name__=="__main__":
    Application()
```

But It's impossible to use threading every time I meet the loop(Too difficult and In some cases, it must be executed sequentially). Is there any useful/easy way to deal with it?

Comment: Try removing `time.sleep(1)`. If you need to slow text insertion try using `after`.

Comment: You can't run a loop in an event handler.  Tkinter, like all GUI frameworks, is event-driven.  When you create or modify a window, nothing gets drawn.  All that does is send a message to the control.  When your code gets back to the main loop, that's when the messages are fetched and processed.  Your handlers must run quickly and return so that the messages can be handled.  Thus, you must use `root.after` to request a callback in one second.  You do the update for that second, call `root.after` again, and return.

Comment: Also, ALL Tkinter updates must be done in the main thread.  You cannot do UI updates in a secondary thread.  This is also true for all of the GUI frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out a better way to target the interface not updating problem caused by other loops or multithreading in tkinter loop practice. As long as the function operation function in the window class `MainWindows` is opened with a sub-thread, no matter how many loops or multi-threading (thread pool) there are in this function opened by the sub-thread, it will not affect the GUI update, and can Real-time scrolling of logs.

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
import requests
from threading import Thread
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
class MainWindows(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master=master)
        self.master=master
        self.createWidget()
        self.pack()
        pass

    def createWidget(self):
        self.text = Text(self, width=50, height=20, relief=SOLID, borderwidth=1, fg="gray")
        self.text.pack()

        self.button = Button(self, text="click", command=self.thread)
        self.button.pack()
        pass

    def thread_show_info(self, i):
        self.text.insert(END, chars=str(i)+'\n')
        self.text.see(END)
        time.sleep(1)

    def threadpool_show_info(self):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as t:
            for q in range(1, 1000):
                t.submit(self.thread_show_info, i=q)

    def thread(self):
        t1 = Thread(target=self.threadpool_show_info,daemon=True)
        t1.start()


if __name__=="__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title('test')
    root.geometry('400x300+450+100')
    a = MainWindows(master=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a method to insert text at a given speed then this can be achieved using tkinter `after`.

The code attempts to clarify usage of `after`.

The process can be interrupted by pressing Escape key. This will `cancel_after` and complete text insertion without delay.

```py
import tkinter as tk

data = dir(tk) # or str.split('\n')

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, undo = 1, wrap = tk.NONE)
text.pack()

def insert_text():
    global delay

    d = data.pop(0)
    text.insert(tk.END, f"{d}\n")
    if len(data) > 0:
        delay = root.after(500, insert_text)

# cancel timed input
def stop(event):
    
    root.after_cancel(delay)
    for d in data:
        text.insert(tk.END, f"{d}\n")

root.bind("<Escape>", stop)

# start output
delay = root.after(50, insert_text)

root.mainloop()
```